# Permission denied when executing a program on mapped network drive

Tags: networking, fstab

I have mapped a network drive to my ubuntu 16 system. Below is my fstab file in /etc/fstab

```
//share/wallets /media/wallets cifs _netdev,comment=systemd.automount,auto,owner,credentials=/home/laptop/.smbcredential,uid=1000,gid=1000,ioc00,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,exec 0 0
```

I can upload files no problem, but I cannot execute files on the network drive. It gives me a permission denied error which does work on my local drive. I have tried chmod